# sencha touch: how to play audio and hide the player from view

Tags: audio, sencha-touch

The audio example on the Kitchen Sink doesn't seem to work since I'm not hearing anything or seeing any player on the screen. I don't know if my browser or my laptop is not working properly but I'll take the risk of asking here if there really is something wrong with the code.

The usual code for including an audio file in Sencha Touch is usually like this:

```
{  xtype: 'audio', url: "who-goingmobile.mp3"  }
```

This was the sample code shown in the Sencha Touch API. I've tried doing it but the audio player still won't play or show in my browser. Please help, thanks.

Comment: check this out http://what-when-how.com/iphone-javascript/playing-an-audio-file-mastering-sound-and-music-iphone-javascript/

Comment: Could I request a clarification? Didn't it play in your browser or in your real device only?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
xtype: 'audio',
url: 'who-goingmobile.mp3',
id: 'sound1',
hidden:true
}
```

Then add a button play on the code or simply add

```
Ext.getCmp('sound1').play();
```